# Excluding objects / layers from post-processing in Three.js

Tags: 3d, three.js, shader

What is the best way to exclude certain objects or (ideally) a layer of objects from post-processing?

For example, I want to have a complex background scene rendered out with various post-process effects (SSAO, tilt-shift, etc) and then overlay another layer of 3D objects without the post-processing effects on them.

I was thinking that I could have 2 completely different WebGL renderers on top of each other (with transparent backgrounds) but I want the 2 layers to be integrated with each other, so it looks like the non-processed layer objects are integrated / on top of the processed layer objects.

If it helps, I'm not so fussed about the tilt-shift effecting the second layer – I'm most interested in making sure the second layer doesn't have SSAO applied.

I hope this makes at least some sense. I wanted to ask here before I go down too deep of a rabbit hole when there's likely a perfect approach that I don't know about. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you use `THREE.EffectComposer` for the post-processing. Take a look at [the advanced post-processing example](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_postprocessing_advanced.html) and how it uses a `MaskPass` (which utilizes the stencil buffer) in the `EffectComposer` to limit certain post-processing (blur) to the background. You also need to have your background objects and foreground objects in separate scenes.

Comment: Thank you! That's plenty to get me started :)

Comment: Link is broken :(